# Information from an EEC-IV on 92 Ford F150

Tags: ford, f-150, computer

Good evening. My general question is, what information, preferably real time, can be obtained from the `EEC` on a 92 `Ford` `F150`? I'm particularly looking to hook up an `Arduino` and digitizing the gauges and information without installing additional, possibly unnecessary, hardware.

Can you monitor the RPMs, Speed, Engine Temperature, Battery Level, Mileage, Oil Pressure, etc in real time from the `EEC`?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. The EEC-IV has a stored code memory that keeps track of engine problems while it is running but requires you to turn on the diagnostic mode to get those codes. There is also a Key-Off-Engine-Running diagnostic mode that requires you to perform some specific steps while the car is parked and warmed up to diagnose problems that only manifest themselves while running. However, I don't believe there is an interactive read mode such as that provided by ODB-II systems.

Comment: I was kind of thinking that might be the case. Oh well. I guess it's on to adding hardware/sensors then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you plan on creating a hardware/software solution from scratch, it is possible.
Moetes QuarterHorse(QH) is hardware that can already read information.
TunerPro software will communicate with QH.

And a pure software solution already exists to connect to the test connector:
ForDiag.cz